# Problem in redirecting subdomain to sub folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a folder named "blog" inside root folder of my site.

I want to redirect `http://example.com/blog/` to `http://blog.example.com/`

The htaccess I am using so far has no luck. The .htaccess contains following code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1
```

I am getting following error:

> This site can't be reached.
>   blog.example.com's server IP address could not be found.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That error message indicates that your issue is not rewriting, but name resolution!

Comment: If you own "example.com", you have to configure your nameserver / domain registrar and add a dns record for subdomains. It seems there's no record tha matches `blog.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the name resolution.

You need to add the following dns entry

```
Type:
  A 
Name:
  {The name of the subdomain E.G "examples" for examples.example.com}
Value:
  {The ip address of your server, just use the same as used in either www or @}
```

Comment: OK but at where I need to add these dns entry?